# App Crashes in Android Studio when button to next activity is pressed

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I am trying to go from the homepage of my app to the next activity, but the app crashes when the button is clicked.

This is the code in the `MainActivity.java` file:

```
    import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
           public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      }

      /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
      public void onSignUpButtonClick(View view) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, goal.class);
          startActivity(intent);
      }
  }
```

Here is the code for the button in the XML file:

```
     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/croissantone"
        android:onClick="onSignUpButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.862" />
```

'''

```
This is the code for the goal.xml file
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_goal2"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

'''
This is the code in the goal.java file 
    public class goal extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoalBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = GoalBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_goal2);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
    }

}
```

The emulator also gives me a message stating that the UI is not responding. All things were working well before the implementation of the button.

'''
The following is the LogCat:
2022-04-16 14:41:50.624 20509-20509/com.cpst343.happymacro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cpst343.happymacro, PID: 20509
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cpst343.happymacro/com.cpst343.happymacro.goal}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.cpst343.happymacro:layout/goal: Binary XML file line #9 in com.cpst343.happymacro:layout/goal: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.cpst343.happymacro:layout/goal: Binary XML file line #9 in com.cpst343.happymacro:layout/goal: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.cpst343.happymacro:layout/goal: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
at com.cpst343.happymacro.databinding.GoalBinding.inflate(GoalBinding.java:49)
at com.cpst343.happymacro.databinding.GoalBinding.inflate(GoalBinding.java:43)
at com.cpst343.happymacro.goal.onCreate(goal.java:23)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Maximum number of items supported by BottomNavigationView is 5. Limit can be checked with BottomNavigationView#getMaxItemCount()
at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarMenu.addInternal(NavigationBarMenu.java:67)
2022-04-16 14:41:50.625 20509-20509/com.cpst343.happymacro E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.add(MenuBuilder.java:476)
at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:531)
at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:207)
at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:129)
at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView.inflateMenu(NavigationBarView.java:384)
at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView.(NavigationBarView.java:280)
at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.(BottomNavigationView.java:108)
at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.(BottomNavigationView.java:103)
at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.(BottomNavigationView.java:98)
... 27 more

Comment: Check the logs in android studio. They will show you an error message with more details for the crash.

Comment: can you share the error logs?

Comment: Please share your goal.java code. Error may be in that activity.

Comment: I think that it's look good. Maybe the error is in your goal Activity. Also you can check for the correct name of your goal class name, it will be more readable if the name starts with capital wetter

Comment: I have shared the logs and the code for goal.java and goal.xml. I appreciate all the feedback!